# Using subquery in insert statment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO someTable (xID, yID, zID) 
VALUES ('1', (
              SELECT aID 
              FROM someTable 
              WHERE something),
        '1')
```

However, for the sub query, if it cannot find a result it returns 0, which I do not want. Is there a way to check that if the sub query returns 0, that I exit the query?

Comment: By the way, the subquery would return `NULL` if there is no match, not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without the `values` statement:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (xID, yID, zID)
    SELECT '1', aID, '1'
    FROM someTable
    WHERE something;
```

I think that fixes your problem.  If there is no match in the query, then nothing is inserted.